# How to get the array of strings that is in between curly braces inside source string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax, arrays, string

Suppose the JavaScript variable is:

```
var sourceString="stack {overflow} is the best {place} to clear {technical} doubts";
```

Output javascript string array should contain: `overflow,place,technical`
or `{overflow},{place},{technical}`

I am fine with both the results.

Comment: And what have you tried?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use regex to accomplish this:

```
sourceString.match(/{.*?}/g)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var getMatchingGroups = function(s) {
  var r=/\{(.*?)\}/g, a=[], m;
  while (m = r.exec(s)) {
    a.push(m[1]);
  }
  return a;
};

getMatchingGroups(sourceString) // ["overflow", "place", "technical"]
```